# B2C Custom Sign Up - Debugging claims exchange with external API

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am following this tutorial

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-rest-api-netfw

I've customised it since my objective here is to prevent anyone from signing up with a display name that already exists

However, I always get the error "The claims exchange 'REST-API-SignUp' specified in step '2' returned HTTP error response that could not be parsed."

I have tested the endpoint with postman, using this model, and it returns as expected

```
public class InputClaimsModel
{
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }

}

public class OutputClaimsModel
{
    public string uniqueName { get; set; }
}
```

If I could debug that message I might be able to find out more but unsure how I can do so?

Extract of Trust Framework Extension is this

```xml
<BasePolicy>
   <TenantId>null.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
  <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase</PolicyId>
</BasePolicy>
<BuildingBlocks>
<ClaimsSchema>
  <ClaimType Id="uniqueName">
    <DisplayName>uniqueName</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <UserHelpText>Customer unique name</UserHelpText>
  </ClaimType>
</ClaimsSchema>
</BuildingBlocks>
<ClaimsProviders>
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>REST APIs</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <!-- Custom Restful service -->
    <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-API-SignUp">
      <DisplayName>Validate user's input data and return unique name claim</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://null.azurewebsites.NET/api/AzureB2C/validate</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
        <!-- Set AuthenticationType to Basic or ClientCertificate in production environments -->
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Basic</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationUsername" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_B2cRestClientId" />
        <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationPassword" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_B2cRestClientSecret" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="firstName" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="lastName" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="uniqueName" PartnerClaimType="uniqueName" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
    <!-- Change LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail technical profile to support your validation technical profile -->
    <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="uniqueName" PartnerClaimType="uniqueName" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-API-SignUp" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Sign up sign in extract

```xml
      <BasePolicy>
        <TenantId>null.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
        <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
      </BasePolicy>
    <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="uniqueName" DefaultValue="" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

The API is supposed to return a response via this

```
public class B2CResponseContent
{
    public string version { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public string userMessage { get; set; }

    public B2CResponseContent(string message, HttpStatusCode status)
    {
        this.userMessage = message;
        this.status = (int)status;
        this.version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: How you are returning data from Web API? use this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, OutputClaimsModel); and see how it is working.

Comment: I copied the example which has something similar, I've edited the above and added it to the sample, but as mentioned I can't see how to read that - postman simply shows me there's an object returned of the expected type

Comment: Did you put Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, OutputClaimsModel); ?

Comment: The version of ASP.NET I am using doesn't appear to support that

Comment: I think I'm basically going to just bite the bullet and port the API to the latest version of .NET, I'm going to have to do it to be able to implement API level security anyway instead of letting the app service do it

Answer (score 1):

A successful response should be returned like this:

```cs
return Ok(outputClaimsModel);
```

which returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "uniqueName": "Chris Padgett"
}
```

It's only a failed response that should be returned using the `B2CResponseContent` model.

In order to troubleshoot the unexpected response, you'll have to [send the Azure AD B2C logs to Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights).

Comment: It works...! The success one anyway. My fault entirely, was a typo in the API with the wrong response type. I still have to figure out how to make it handle the fail scenario though